# Why did i get every time an Syntax error when i try to put an Variable in an Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
def Colour(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-style-name="'colour'"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Every Time i Become an Syntax error and when i dont become an syntax error Python dont detect the Variable.

Comment: try this ```f'//a[@data-style-name={colour}]'``` . Notice that you need to add the ```f```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the format tool for the string and make sure to alternate your quotes. 
You can use double on the outside and single on the inside or the opposite.
Then use {} to instantiate a location for the variable and .format(variable_name) at the end of the string.

```
def Colour(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-style-name="{}"]'.format(color)).click()
    time.sleep(1)
```